# API rest não receber nada de outro App que não seja o meu

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api

Tem como impedir que outra aplicação mande ou receba informações do meu REST?

Comment: Que tal fazer uma autenticação?

Comment: Como o @LINQ falou, tem que implementar uma autenticação na API. Ou usar filtro por certificado, ou outra forma de segurança nela que impeça qualquer um diferente da sua aplicação de obter informação.

Comment: Entendi. Eu estava fazendo uma espécie de um token para validar, acho que é mais ou menos isso que vocês estão falando, certo?

Comment: Autenticação é muito mais que um "token". Recomendo que você trabalhe com técnicas já existente de autenticação do que fazer do zero.

Comment: Valeu a todo, obrigado..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realize uma pesquisa sobre implementar oAuth. 
Esse protocolo permite autenticar aplicativos externos de acordo com permissões do usuário.